# How to get NSLayoutConstraint's identifier by Its pointer?

Tags: ios, debugging, nslayoutconstraint, xcode7-beta4

I setup in Storyboard `identifier` for each constraint:

[image]

Now I get error with `unsatisfiable constraints`. I try to debug this by printing constraint's pointer:

```
po 0x17db78d0
```

Now to order investigate what constraint it is, I would like to print its `identifier` just like:

```
po 0x17db78d0.identifer.
```

...but it is not working. I get an error:

> error: hexadecimal floating constants require an exponent
>
> error: 1 errors parsing expression

Hence, how to print identifier for specific `NSLayoutConstraint`?

Comment: This whole article can be pretty helpful, but in your case I'd check the debugging section: http://www.objc.io/issues/3-views/advanced-auto-layout-toolbox/#debugging.

Comment: Alternatively, you could create an `IBOutlet` for the `NSLayoutConstraint` and then check the outlet in code.

Answer (score 2):

`po ((NSLayoutConstraint *)0x17db78d0).identifier`