# How to use constraint Identifiers in autolayout and how to change constrain using identifiers? [Swift]

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, xcode7

While I was editing my constraint in Xcode 7 I found **identifier** field in  Interface Builder. What is an identifier for the constraint how do I use it? using identifier can I access constraint programmatically and change the constant? my question is why and how is that identifier is helpful?

[image: SNAPSHOT]

Is there any way to access the constraint with an identifier with looping in subviews and again looping constrain subviews. I mean is there any way we can access constraint directly without a loop.

> UPDATE

I Tryed this code but only width and height constrain is accessed

```
    for subview in view.subviews {
        for constraint in subview.constraints() {
           if constraint.identifier == "identifier" {
                return constraint
           }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27791597/is-there-a-way-to-add-an-identifier-to-auto-layout-constraints-in-interface-buil/31831576#31831576

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33038451/get-reference-to-nslayoutconstraint-using-identifier-set-in-storyboard

Comment: @oyalhi i updated the question ..

Comment: @EICaptain i updated my question

Comment: if you have constraint error , you can debug your constraint using identifier

Comment: @O-mkar please check this out this one works for me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44558288/6897825

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**HOW:** The identifier is useful when **debugging** (e.g. constraints not matching and one of them gets broken at run time; the constraint identifiers are being shown in log so you can see which one might cause problems)

**WHY:** Constraint identifiers make logs easier to read, more accurate and they save you a lot of time.

**Constraint editing:** If you want to change constraints programmatically you will have to declare them as **outlets** (like a label or button), then remove them from the view (NOT the object itself) and then set them again to the view. From my knowledge you can't just "edit" the constraints programmatically.

Your code gives you only width and height because you access the view's constraints which only contains the objects' widths and heights.

Comment: It is actually possible to modify a constraint after you have declared it as an outlet, like this: self.myConstraint.constant = 50.0

Answer (score 5):

#### In Swift 4 it's possible:

With this extension:

```
extension UIView{
    func constraintWith(identifier: String) -> NSLayoutConstraint?{
        return self.constraints.first(where: {$0.identifier == identifier})
    }
}
```

And you can use't this way:

```
 if let myConstraint = myView.constraintWith(identifier: "myConstraintID"){
     myConstraint.constant = 8
 }
```

Ps: Be sure to call `constraintWith(identifier: String)` on the view where the constraint was added, normally on the superView of the related view you are changing, or on itself if the constraint is for size (width/height)

Comment: More accurately, if you want to access the height, width, or aspect ratio of the view, call this method on that `view` itself. On the other hand, to access other constraints such as leading or trailing, call this method on the `SuperView` that contains the view.

Comment: @rule_it_subir it all depends the way you setup your constraints

Answer (score 1):

To supplement the answer answer, we are also able to set constraints programmatically, and it was easier than I thought:

```swift
        let yConstraint = imageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layout.centerYAnchor)
        yConstraint.identifier = "yConstraint"
        let xConstraint = imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layout.centerXAnchor)
            xConstraint.identifier = "xConstraint"

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            yConstraint,
            xConstraint
        ])
```

Then, it showed up in the console, albeit difficult to read still...

```
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000025fe490 'xConstraint' UIImageView:0x7f8f41107fa0.centerX == UILayoutGuide:0x600003fcc1c0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.centerX   (active)>
```