# UINavigationBar height when controller presenting modal in iOS 13

Tags: ios, uitableview, modalviewcontroller, ios13

Controller presents with the following code:

```
let vc = UIViewController()
vc.view.backgroundColor = Colors.green
let nvc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
self.present(nvc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

It shows

[image: original]

but the navigation bar height is big. It should be like this

[image: shouldbe]

How to do the navigation bar height like on the second image?

Answer (score 3):

From [the discussion in apple developer forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/378841#378841), this seems to be a bug in iOS 13.
And the workaround they provide there is as following:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {  
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)  
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {  
        navigationController?.navigationBar.setNeedsLayout()  
    }
}
```

I've tested it in my project and it solved the problem. Hope it solves yours too.

Comment: for me, I have to put these code inside `DispatchQueue.main.async{}` to make it work.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

The navigation bar is actually in the right size (at least for iOS 13 standards) when the stack is not too deep. The navigation bar becomes smaller for a view presented at index 2 (and later?)

To resize the navigation bar, follow these two steps:

1. Get the default height constraint (with name `"UI-View-Encapsulated-Layout-Height"`). To do this, search among the navigation bar's constraints. I've shamelessly copied [Isaih Turner's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33038451/get-reference-to-nslayoutconstraint-using-identifier-set-in-storyboard) below, which makes it easier.

   ```
   extension UIView {
       /// Returns the first constraint with the given identifier, if available.
       ///
       /// - Parameter identifier: The constraint identifier.
       func constraintWithIdentifier(_ identifier: String) -> NSLayoutConstraint? {
           return self.constraints.first { $0.identifier == identifier }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Set the constant to the desired value.

   ```
   let existingConstraint = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.constraintWithIdentifier("UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height")
   existingConstraint?.constant = 88.0
   self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setNeedsLayout()
   ```

And you're done.